# Why are the files not being included

Tags: c++, include, sfml

This is my first time attempting a big project in C++, and I wanted to create a game in SFML. I divided my program into a bunch of classes that included each other, and that's where I am getting my error.
I have three main classes, `Game`, `State`, and `Entity`. The `main.cpp` includes the `Game.h` file and starts the game. The `Game.h` file is where all the SFML includes are. Here is a simplified version of my code.

---

#### main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    // starts the game here
}
```

#### Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "State.h"
// All the SFML includes and other standard library includes are here

class Game
{
}

#endif
```

#### State.h

```
#ifndef STATE_H
#define STATE_H

#include "Entity.h"

class State
{
}

#endif
```

#### Entity.h

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H
#define ENTITY_H

#include "Game.h"

class Entity
{
}

#endif
```

Theoretically, `State.h` should be able to access the SFML functions because it is including `Entity.h` which is including `Game.h` which is including SFML. But when I add SFML functions into either `State.h` and `Entity.h`, visual studio doesn't show any errors until I compile it, where it says that the functions aren't defined.

Comment: You have cyclic header dependencies. Consider what the preprocessor's output for `main.cpp` will be. You'll end up with a verbatim copy of `Entity.h`, `State.h` and `Game.h`, in that order. However, the declarations from `Entity.h` depend on declarations from `Game.h`, which don't appear until later in the translation unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an include cycle:

Game.h includes state.h which includes entity.h which includes game.h.

You need to find a way to break the cycle. Typically, you do that with a forward declaration in the header:

```
class State;
```

And then include the .h in the .cpp file.